# How to query Excel sheet to get result from nth row?

Tags: c#, oledbcommand

I need to import data from excel sheet where 1st 3 rows contain header information(to be skipped). 
and again i want to apply a where clause to get the exact result.
something like `name!=""`.

I am using OLEDB Connection and the query is `string query = string.Format("Select * from [{0}] ", excelSheets[1]);`

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Have you considered using something like [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML)?  It makes selecting from excel files extremely simple

Comment: @TimHutchison thanks for that suggestion, but i am all done with this code, i stuck in that query.